# What is the best way to store and retrieve many small text documents for flask web app

Tags: database, file, nosql

I'm writing an app which will store around 135,000 small text documents, total size 2GB, mostly around 15kB but the largest is 340kB, adding ~500 a day. I'd like to be able to scale to 1 million documents.

At the moment I am using a nested directory structure to store the documents, as this makes human navigation of the files more convenient than a single huge directory. One thing that I have noticed though is that copying the files is a pain. I can use rsync to back them up which works but I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.

The alternatives are:

- Current solution - nested directories of text files.
- Concatenate files into text blobs, and store the offsets (I have a database which indexes the files where I can store offsets)
- Store the files in a sql database, as TEXT fields.
- Store the files in a no-sql database, e.g. cassandra or mongodb.

I have no experience with nosql databases at all, I was wondering is that a usual use case for these tools? I am using flask and python on linux, and postgresql at the moment but this is not a restriction.

---

Just to add some context to this - I tried copying the 135,000 files to a new folder. This took 10 minutes. Opening and reading all the files from python took ~10 minutes. Opening and reading a tar of all the files in 15kB chunks took sub one minute. So it seems there is a huge overhead in using the file system to manage record look up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a lot of the files have the same structure?  Can you, perhaps, merge or concatenate 135k files into a few dozen types?  If so, you should be able to bulk load many small files into a dataframe and then push the dataframe into a table in, let's say SQL Server.  If the files are all different in form and type, you'll have to come up with a more innovative solution, as it wouldn't make any sense at all to have 135k tables in your database.  If this is the case, maybe MongoDB would be an option.